# Why does my MSDOS application show Unix file dates off by 20 days?

Tags: date, dos, nfs

I have an MSDOS 6.22 application which uses NFS to access files on a Unix server.  It shows file dates 20 days older than the actual file date on the server.   A DIR command shows the same incorrect date.   A Wireshark trace shows that the Unix server does pass the file modification date correctly as seconds since 1970 in the ‘mtime’ field.   Why does the date appear wrong to the DOS applications?

Comment: MSDOS? I'm torn as to whether this should be on the retro computing  sister site or not :-)

Comment: This discovery was on a group of factory computers still running 24 hour production.  But you're right in that people probably would first search for this stuff in the retro site (which I didn't know about before posting).

Answer (score 2):

Check for the presence of a TZ environment variable, and if used, run a test without TZ.   The MSDOS Borland / Turbo C library function unixtodos() uses the TZ variable, but performs no validity checks.  So a TZ value of GMT+0500 or GHO+0500 for example (from a Ghost installation) will cause a date shift of many days.